# org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException when using @JoinTable

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa, orm, foreign-keys

This is my database:

```
------------       ----------------------       ------------
|   NEWS   |       |     NEWS_IMAGE     |       |  IMAGE   |
------------       ----------------------       ------------
| id | text|       | id_news | id_image |       | id | URL |
------------       ----------------------       ------------
  |                      |       |                |
  <-<-<-<-<-<- Foreign Key       Foreign Key ->->->
```

In the object **News** I have a `List` of object **Image**. Here is my mapping system:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news")
class News{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinTable(name = "news_image",
              joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_news")},
              inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_image")})   
              private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();}
```

And this is the object **Image**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "URL")
   private String URL;
}
```

This is the way I delete an Object Image:

```
News news  = org.hibernate.SessionFactory.get(News.class, id);
Image image = news.getImages().get(0);  
org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSessionFactory().delete(image);
```

When I try to delete an Image from the table **image** I get this error:

```
Could not execute JDBC batch update;
SQL [delete from image where id=?];
constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
Could not execute JDBC batch update.
```

If I remove the foreign key from the table **news_image** to the table **image**, everything works fine; Hibernate is able to delete first the record inside the table **news_image**  and then the record inside the table **image**.
What should I do? Should I remove that foreign Key? Did I make an error while mapping and that's why I get that error?

Thank in advance.

Comment: You have a problem deleting an Image but yet you fail to post the code for the Image entity nor any code around your call to delete???

Comment: Sorry man. I added some code about object Image and the way I delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your mappings stand, `Image` does not know anything about the association to `News` so the corresponding record in the `NEWS_IMAGE` association table will never be deleted by Hibernate as it knows nothing about it.

To fix this you can either update your code as below:

```
//News is managing the association to Image and has Cascade options defined
//so we need to update and merge the News instance
News news  = org.hibernate.SessionFactory.get(News.class, id);
Image image = news.getImages().get(0);  
news.getImages().remove(image);
org.hibernate.SessionFactory.getCurrentSessionFactory().saveOrUpdate(news);
```

Or you can update your mappings so that Image knows about the association and proceed as before:

News:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "news")
class News{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue
   @Column(name = "id")
   private long id;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "news", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
   private List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
}
```

Image:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "image")
public class Image {

   @Id
   @Column(name = "id")
   @GeneratedValue
   private long id;

   @Column(name = "URL")
   private String URL;

   @ManyToOne( cascade = CascadeType.DELETE)
   @JoinTable(name = "news_image",
              joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_image")},
              inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "id_news")})   
   private News news;

}
```

Comment: Thank you man. While you were answering I edited my post, adding a mappinmg system, inside Image (exactely like you wrote), but I left the old mapping system inside News; it seems to work. But I can't understand if having @JoinTable on both News.class and Image.class can lead me to some problems in the future.. 
Anyway thank for the solution, perfect like all the others you gave me in the past :D

Comment: No, you use mappedBy on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete from the join table first, then you can delete from the child table.

```
delete pc.* from parent_child as pc left join child as c on pc.id_child=c.id where c.id = 1;
delete from child where child.id = 1;
```

Comment: Really? Why no normal cascade operation?

Comment: I didn't try to do it in JPQL because the poster seems to be using SQL.

Comment: Actually I need to use Cascade Operation. I added some code